# After what point a JavaScript library is considered as a FrameWork?

Tags: frameworks, javascript

I am kind of confused with the definitions.

Can you please define the minimum "must haves" of a JavaScript library so that it can be considered as a software framework?

thanks

Answer (score 9):

The distinction between a framework and a library is pretty fuzzy, in my opinion. Generally, software frameworks are larger-scale and usually "take over" your application (since they provide a basis, or "framework", for your application to be built upon). A library, on the other hand, just offers a collection of functions you can pick and choose from.

Wikipedia has some [specific criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) for distinguishing frameworks from libraries as well:

> 1. inversion of control - In a framework, unlike in libraries or normal user applications, the overall program's flow of control is not dictated by the caller, but by the framework.
> 2. default behavior - A framework has a default behavior. This default behavior must actually be some useful behavior and not a series of no-ops.
> 3. extensibility - A framework can be extended by the user usually by selective overriding or specialized by user code providing specific functionality.
> 4. non-modifiable framework code - The framework code, in general, is not allowed to be modified. Users can extend the framework, but not modify its code.